# ATG UNABLE TO START SERVICE

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I am just trying to insert the values in OOTB table "dps_user", which was working fine. When I tried to extend the table (dps_user), I have given item-descriptor as "user" in the XML file which I verified using dys/admin also.

Now while trying to execute it I was getting error as item descriptor "user" not found in the console and NullPointerException while executing jsp page. I even tried creating a new JSP page with only the OOTB Extension, but I am getting the same error.

In addition, while starting the server I am getting an error message as unable to start service-atg/userprofile, etc. How do I forgo these errors?

Comment: Can you post the errors verbatim (by editing the question)?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @AnshuKumar ,With help of debug I was able to solve it myself thank u.There was a small logical eror